# How to store Revit Add-in Settings with Python?

Tags: python, revit-api, pyrevit

My Revit Add-in reads at some point a text file, that could be located anywhere. In my current implementation, the path to the text file is hardcoded. I'd like to avoid that, so that when I distribute the Add-in to other people, it doesn't simply crash.

Ideally I'd like to give them the ability of specifying their own location for that file on their computer, **and that they don't need to re-specify it every time they re-launch the Add-in**! 
In other words, I'd like to store once and for all this information. And if you close and re-open Revit, the location is still stored somewhere when you re-use the Addin.

This question is actually similar to [this one](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/03/storing-revit-add-in-settings.html), except that I'd need a solution when developing in Python (**pyRevit**). Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're developing you addon in pyRevit, then you can use the `pyrevit.script` module to get the configuration for that script.

Ask user for the file location (`pyrevit.forms.save_file` helps) and then save the file path in the script configuration. pyRevit handles this automatically and saves the information inside its master configuration file at `%appdata%/pyRevit`

```
from pyrevit import script
config = script.get_config()
config.filelocation = 'path/to/your/file'
script.save_config()
```

And then later, read the configuration like this:

```
from pyrevit import script
config = script.get_config()
print(config.filelocation)
# or to get the config safely
print(config.get_option('filelocation', None)
```

Answer (score 2):

I implemented two other ways to store Revit add-in settings in the [HoloLens Escape Path Waypoint JSON Exporter](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/09/hololens-escape-path-waypoint-json-exporter.html):

- Store add-in option settings in XML using the .NET `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase` class
- Store add-in option settings in JSON using custom solution and `JavaScriptSerializer` class

Both solutions are well suited for what you need.

Check them out in the [ExportWaypointsJson GitHub repository](https://github.com/jeremytammik/ExportWaypointsJson).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy!